# Can a class object know its "parent"?

Tags: python

I'm not sure if i'm wording this correctly, but is there a way for a class "variable" to know its "parent"?   Maybe a way overriding __ new __?  since There's never an instance of A being created, i can't think of a way.   eg see below:

```
class B(object):
    def return_parent_class(self):
         #here's where i'd like to see what the class is 
         return []  

class A(object):
    thingie = B() 

class C(A):
    value = 1


class D(A):
    value = 2


C.thingie.return_parent_class().value  # would like to equal 1
D.thingie.return_parent_class().value  # would like to equal 2
```

Comment: So what should be returned when *more than one object* references the same `B()` instance? What if that is a list or dictionary? Would you want to differentiate between dictionary keys and values? What about the stack, or local names? Python is **full** of references, there rarely is just one 'parent'. Pass in a parent reference explicitly if you need one.

Comment: In short: this is a really bad idea and destroys any sanity in application architecture. Think of something else. Something… **explicit**.

Comment: User has define value as class variable, but I think he wants to define it as instance variable but he is not sure on how to do that

Comment: As Homer almost wrote, it is a wise subclass that knows its own parent...

Comment: What about inspect.getmro(C))? 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro

Comment: Thanks for for your responses everyone!

A little background as to why:   I'm trying to accomplish something similar to the how the models.Manager  class in Django works.   

eg when you write Model.objects.get()    it generates a SQL query to the backend database around the metadata from that "parent" class.    Same in this situation, i'd like the "return_parent_class" to know what class it came from so that it can "inspect" it and generate a similar sql query.

i'm a little lost into how django does it, so perhaps it's doing it in a more pythonic way.